# Creating a heatmap from data that contains counts

Tags: python, seaborn, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe that looks like this (pictured below), and essentially I want a heatmap that shows the REF -> ALT counts. The heat map should have the x-axis as REF, y-axis as ALT, and the the darker the color- the higher the count.

```
    REF ALT COUNT
0   A   C   3328
1   A   G   11321
2   A   T   3477
3   C   A   3920
4   C   G   3367
5   C   T   11778
6   G   A   11612
7   G   C   3199
8   G   T   3772
9   T   A   3463
10  T   C   11288
11  T   G   3420
```

Comment: For a heat map in seaboard you'll need to reshape the dataframe to a matrix format where the rows represent the REF, the columns represent the ALT, and the values are the COUNT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the dataframe is reshaped correctly you can use the `heatmap` function from `seaborn` to visualize the data.

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
data = {
    'REF': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T'],
    'ALT': ['C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'G'],
    'COUNT': [3328, 11321, 3477, 3920, 3367, 11778, 11612, 3199, 3772, 3463, 11288, 3420]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Reshape the dataframe to a matrix format
pivot_df = df.pivot(index='REF', columns='ALT', values='COUNT')

# Plot the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(pivot_df, annot=True, cmap='YlGnBu', fmt='g', linewidths=.5)
plt.title('REF -> ALT Counts Heatmap')
plt.show()
```

This code will generate a heatmap where the x-axis represents the `REF`, the y-axis represents the `ALT`, and the color intensity is based on the `COUNT` value. The darker the color, the higher the count.